# What is the AUC score in sklearn.metrics?

Tags: scikit-learn, auc

In `sklearn.metrics.auc` [documentation](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.metrics.auc.html) the `auc` score is discussed, but this is different from the regular `roc_auc_score`. I see no description of this, what is it and what is it used for?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`sklearn.auc` is a general fuction to calculate the area under a curve using trapezoid rule. It is used to calculate `sklearn.metrics.roc_auc_score`.

To calculate roc_auc_score, sklearn evaluates the false positive and true positive rates using the `sklearn.metrics.roc_curve` at different threshold settings. Then it uses `sklearn.metrics.auc` to calculate the area under the curves, and finally returns their average binary score.

Answer (score 1):

As the documentation says, it is the area under an arbitrary curve, i.e., the definite integral (computed with the trapezoidal approximation).  Some examples are linked at the bottom of the documentation page showing its use.